# Logical delete with a Time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ado.net, sql-delete

I prefer to delete a record from the database logically rather than physically. Is it better to just flag the record with a "deleted" flag or else is it better to use a time stamp?

For example We can add an additional `DateTime` fields to every tables that we need to perform logical delete. So when deleting you just update the field like...

```
UPDATE Client SET deleted = GETDATE() where Client.CID = @cid
```

If it should be undeleted...

```
UPDATE Client SET deleted = NULL where Client.CID = @cid
```

So that a typical selection statement would look like...

```
SELECT * FROM client WHERE CID = @cid AND deleted IS NULL
```

My primary requirement is that the deleted rows should be able to recover and it should be able to easily implement.

Comment: I would just use the flag, but the question is going to boil down to opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common pattern that a column with a name like "DeletedAt" or "DeletionDate", of type date is used to indicate if the row has been deleted.  So the answer is yes.